# How to partitioning USB stick to act as iso image and to store files at the same time

Tags: partitioning, usb, iso, usb-drive

I have 16 GB USB memory stick, I had burned a Kubuntu 22.04 iso image on it by some how. Today, I need to store some files on that stick, I realized that I have at least over 6 GB of free space on that stick after the space consumed by the iso image. However, I found the free space on it is Zero.

Using the Disk manager (KDE Partition Manager), I found that iso image takes about 3.4 GB in a partition and some other two tiny size partitions there without any **unallocated** space. I had to remove all partitions  to get back the total size of the USB stick again.

The question, **indeed**, is how to make two partitions on that stick, hence, when I need to burn an iso image on it, it should be burned on that partition (*let we say the first partition*) and I will be sure that the other partition (*the second one*) intact because it will carry my data?

Comment: Next time use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventoy

Comment: @FedKad Well, I am going to try it. Thank You!

Comment: **Mkusb** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, will create a bootable Ubuntu USB with a Persistent partition that retains file system changes between boots and includes a partition for data. The USB will boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode. I find it easier to use with persistence than Ventoy. Ventoy is great if you want to try multiple Linux operating systems.

Comment: @FedKad I have tried Ventoy. It is amazing! 

Comment: This is the [download link](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html) of **Ventoy**